# Convergence of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}} f(n)\mathrm{log}(n)$

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

A function $f(n)$ has the following conditions:
$$
f(n),n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}
$$
$$
f(n)\in[0,1]
$$
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}} f(n)=1
$$

Does the following sum always converge? Or does a function $f(n)$ exist for which the sum does diverge? Or when does the sum converge?

$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}} f(n)\mathrm{log}(n)
$$

I already tested e.g. $f(n)=2^{-n}$.

Thank you

Comment: I think there's probably some adaptation (translation/rescaling/etc) of $f(n) = \frac{1}{n \log^2 n}$ which should make the first sum converge and the second diverge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with $f(n):= \frac{1}{n \log(n)^2}$ and the Bertrand sum criterion.

Comment: Oke, cool:) it works. If $f(1)=0$ then the first sum converges and the second diverges. Thank you very much:)!